# Who is the woman of a similar age to Wit?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

In *Words of Radiance*, chapter 55, after Shallan hugs Wit (aka Hoid), Adolin jealously tells Wit:

> Stick to women your own age.

To which Wit cryptically replies:

> Well, that might be a little harder. I think there's only one of
>   those around these parts, and she and I never did get along.

Are there any hints as to whom he might be referring to?

Comment: Complete speculation, but the only character that's been introduced so far that this might be is the NIghtwatcher.  Granted, she's referred to as a 'powerful spren', but given her abilities it's entirely possible that she's actually a shardholder.

Comment: The Nightwatcher isn't a woman, just a spren of Cultivation. Wit was probably referring to Cultivation herself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hoid is said to have been at the shattering of Adonalsium (this is obviously not said in the books where precious few know that event, but has been confirmed [by the author to various fans](http://twg.17thshard.com/index.php?topic=7302.msg0#msg0), and is backed up by the fact that he knows most of the Shardholders by their original names).  That event was millenia ago.

So basically, the only woman his age that would be around would be a Shardholder holding one of the god-powers from that event.  **Which basically means he's probably referring to the bearer of Cultivation,** whose real name I don't believe is known at this point, but who is believed to be female, and is anyway the only Shardholder that isn't either dead or utterly evil in the area.

Comment: Hoid refers to her as "slammer" although that's not her real name. But yeah Sanderson has confirmed that it's Cultivation's vessel he is referring to.

Comment: Actually it's now mentioned in one of letters from Oathbringer that he could become one of "gods" - take a shard, but didn't.

Answer (score 2):

#### It might be Khriss.

> Duchess Khrissalla, better known as Khriss, is a female worldhopper originally from the country of Elis on the Darkside of the shardworld Taldain.
> <sub>[coppermind](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Khrissalla)</sub>

In *Mistborn: Secret History*, it is established that Khriss and Hoid (called The Drifter) don't really get along well.

> “Someone destroyed the gateway in,” Nazh noted. “Someone incredibly foolhardy. Brash. Stupid. Didn’t—”
>
> “You’re overselling it,” Kelsier said. “The Drifter told me what I
> did.” “The . . . who?” Khriss asked.
>
> “Fellow with white hair,” Kelsier said. “Lanky, with a sharp nose
> and—”
>
> “Damn,” Khriss said. “Did he get to the Well of Ascension?”
>
> “Stole something there,” Kelsier said. “A bit of metal.”
>
> “*Damn*,” Khriss said, looking at her servant. “We need to go. I’m sorry, Survivor.”
> <sub>*Mistborn: Secret History - Part 3: Spirit - Chapter 2*</sub>

Khriss is also the [in-universe author](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stormlight_Archive/comments/4nov0o/no_spoilers_first_draft_of_the_stormlight_novella/d4bwlnk/?context=3) of *Ars Arcanum*, which mean she has been to/is on Roshar, and [WoB](http://www.17thshard.com/forum/topic/6743-brandons-answers-in-houston-311-signing/?do=findComment&comment=110173) has establish that she is a more knowledge worldhopper than Hoid.

Comment: It's a good answer, but Khriss appears to have come from Taldain well after that world was claimed by Autonomy (depending on when exactly *White Sand* is being set, hard to tell with only one volume out). So definitely a rival, definitely old... old enough might be out though.